# Listbox carousel - is it possible?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm not using a listbox and data binding at the moment, but is it possible to have a listbox work like a carousel and if so, how.

This is what I'm using at the moment, which only works for adding images, not through binding in a listbox... can it still be modified to position each binded canvas+image in the suggested answer?

```
// add images to the stage
public void addImages()
        {
            var itemCollection = GalleryModel.DocItemCollection;
            foreach (var item in itemCollection)
            {
                var url = item.ImageUrl;
                var image = new Image
                                {
                                    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                                };

                image.Width = 90;
                image.Height = 60;

                // add the image
                LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);

                // Add template here?


                // reposition the image
                posImage(image, itemCollection.IndexOf(item));
                _images.Add(image);

                var containingWidth = ActualWidth;
                var numberofItemsShown = containingWidth/100;
                if (itemCollection.IndexOf(item) < Math.Ceiling(numberofItemsShown)-1)
                    moveIndex(1);
            }
        }




// move the index
private void moveIndex(int value)
        {
            _target += value;
            _target = Math.Max(0, _target);
            _target = Math.Min(_images.Count - 1, _target);
        }

// reposition the image
private void posImage(Image image , int index){
            double diffFactor = index - _current;

            double left = _xCenter - ((IMAGE_WIDTH + OFFSET_FACTOR) * diffFactor);
            double top = _yCenter;

            image.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
            image.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, top);
}
```

Comment: extra note: The images need to be in the canvas for moving around

Comment: In the end, I'm using a listbox with binded content in a scrollviewer. The data template of the list item contains an image and file name. Controlling position through the scrollviewer's offset position. Did have a go at position the listbox using canvas, but gave up and depended on the scrollviewer's offset limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd typically use a `ListBox` for scenarios like this.

The XAML for it would look something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ImageGalleryListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <tkt:WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding MyImageItemUri}" Margin="8" Width="100" Height="100" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You can of course template it further to make things look the way you want.

In the code-behind here or in your view model, you'd create class that has an `MyImageItemUri` property and add instances of it to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. You can then bind or set the collection to the `ItemsSource` of the `ImageGalleryListBox`. You'd create more images dynamically by simply adding more of your image items to the observable collection.

Comment: This is exactly right. If you want a canvas you can add a canvas instead of a WrapPanel also. Using Canvas.Left and Canvas.Right to bind to a viewmodel to use point layout.

Comment: Not sure how I can reposition each image in the collection (on scroll, mouse click) of the carousel I'm working on if the image is a binded one in the data template...

Comment: Here is an image carousel implementation example I found: [ http://the-oliver.com/2010/03/09/image-carousel-in-silverlight/ ]. It derives from a simple `Panel` so you can use it as the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` template.